# Create dynamic layer based on a query in ArcGIS Pro: "ERROR 000055: Cannot create a Query Table for this workspace" when using "Make Query Table"

Tags: arcgis-pro, sql-server, query-table

I have connected the SQL database server `myserver` in ArcGIS Pro. It then appears as `myserver.sde` under Databases in the Catalog window. Points can be visualized in a map with the fields `X` and `Y` (EPSG:2056) from its table `dbo.mytable` by:

```
1. Right-click on dbo.mytable > Add To Current Map
2. Right-click on the Standalone Table dbo.mytable in Contents Window > Display XY Data
```

However, the points visualized in the map by this process do not react dynamically on modifications in the database. This is due to the problem, that a copy of the table is created as [no primary key is supplied](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/problem-the-latest-updates-are-not-displayed-in-layers-000005735) by this process. Nevertheless, this approach shows that data from this database connection is readable and visualizable - important to know for the next attempt.

Due to this matter, I alternatively follow the attempt using the geoprocessing tool `Make Query Table` as visible in the image. The message `ERROR 000055: Cannot create a Query Table for this workspace.` appears when running this tool. The details of this error message are:

```
Make Query Table
=====================
Parameters

Input Tables     H:\myfolder\mydatabase.sde\dbo.mytable
Table Name     Locations
Key Field Options     USE_KEY_FIELDS
Key Fields     dbo.mytable.index
Fields     dbo.mytable.index index;dbo.mytable.street street;dbo.mytable.city city
Expression     
=====================
Messages

Start Time: Donnerstag, 17. August 2023 11:30:51
ERROR 000055: Cannot create a Query Table for this workspace
Failed to execute (MakeQueryTable).
Failed at Donnerstag, 17. August 2023 11:30:51 (Elapsed Time: 0.27 seconds)
```

All parameters in this message look fine, i.e. I can not figure out where the problem with the workspace occurs. Where do I have the opportunity to intervene and to define the workspace so the query table, needed for an automatic dynamic data update in the map, will be accepted?

Technical background data:

- SQL server: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Standard (64-bit), Version 15.0.4312.2
- Operating System for SQL server: Windows Server 2022 Standard (10.0)
- ArcGIS Pro: Version 3.1.2
- Operating System for ArcGIS Pro: Windows 11 Pro (22H2)

[image: Make Query Table]

Comment: If you want dynamic geometry, why not populate a geometry column and set a trigger to update the geometry each time the X or Y column is changed? Then you can make a Query Layer on the resulting geometry and get good performance with a spatial index. Note: Your "technical data" doesn't include the version of SQL Server.

Comment: A geometry column was not needed for ArcMap (ArcGIS Desktop). Is this now required for ArcGIS Pro? I have now added the SQL Server version.

Comment: "Not needed" is an exaggeration. It is necessary for adequate performance, and has always been. The "workspace" here is the connection file itself, so you're not getting around the error. You could probably work around the lack of a geometry column by creating a view that computes the geometry on the fly, then simply use a Query **Layer**. It's a kludge, but IMO less so than the Query Table/XY Event Layer combo.

Comment: Creating geometry columns in a View and using Query Layer is the solution. Please write your comment as an answer so I can accept it.